# Turn off notification sounds programmatically after button click on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have only seen ways on how to hide a notification but not anything related to turning off sounds yet. How do I turn off/on the notification sounds from different apps installed on a device, programmatically with a button click? Is it possible for API 29 and higher versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off notification sound by setting your notification priority to low,

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
         // You must set the priority to support Android 7.1 and lower
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW) // Set priority to 
         PRIORITY_LOW to mute notification sound 
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Another thing you can do,

```
myNotification.defaults = 0;
```

Or if you want to set your priority high and mute notification sound use,

```
NotificationCompat.Builder.setNotificationSilent()
```

then create your notification,

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentText("text")
                .setContentTitle("content")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setNotificationSilent() // just keep this line
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setTicker("text"))

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
            }
```

Do not forget to uninstall and install the application

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks for your help.